# Power voltage relation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, power

I have a question concerning the relation between power and voltage.

> We have a lamp with power of 36W when used with 12V. With what power does the lamp work if we connect it to a 6V battery?

First, I took the formula P=UI. From it I concluded that if voltage drops by half so does power, so 18W. 
But when I transform the power formula with Ohm's law to P=U^2/R. Then by reducing voltage by half we reduce power by 4. Therefore I get 9W 
So which formula should we use or what I am missing that makes the answer not add up? 
Edit 1: So thinking a bit more, turns out the first time I assume current stays the same. The second time I assume resistance stays the same. Which one is the logical to choose? Resistivity since we do not switch the lamp?

Comment: Why would you think the resistance of a lamp would change when the voltage changes?

Comment: When I think about it a second time, the usual lamps are constant resistances that is heated up by variable current which emits a photon.

Comment: At an elementary level the assumption to be made is that the resistance of a light bulb is constant and not dependent on the applied voltage.  [As explained here and the links therein](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/458189/car-headlight-voltage/458225#458225) in practice this is not a good assumption for significant variations in the voltage.

Comment: Note that resistance of tungsten lamp at nominal power is typically ten times higher then at room temperature.And that temperature must lead to balanced electrical and radiative power, with the latter proportional to T^4